# uniform continuity in metric space

Tags: real-analysis

> Let the metric space $X=(0,\infty)$ and determine whether the following are uniformly continuous on $X$:
>   (1) $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$
>   (2) $f(x)=1/x$
>   (3) $f(x)=\ln(x)$
>   (4) $f(x)=x\ln(x)$

Since this isn't $\mathbb{R}$ I don't think I can use the usual method: showing that $|f'|$ is bounded.

Any tips on how to solve these problems?

Comment: Are these homework problems?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity) says that "Every Lipschitz continuous map between two metric spaces is uniformly continuous. In particular, every function which is differentiable and has bounded derivative is uniformly continuous."

Comment: @BenjaminLim Yes. Matt N. Unfortunately the lecturer specifically pointed out that we cannot use that property since we have not proven it.

Comment: In the first three cases the functions are monotone. Therefore (if you are trying to show uniform continuity) it suffices to explicitly compute $f(x+\delta) - f(x)$ and show that it is bounded by a function $g(\delta)$ independent of $x$ with $g(\delta)\to 0$ as $\delta \to 0$.

Comment: OTOH, if you don't have bounded derivatives, do you know how to demonstrate a contradiction to uniform continuity? In particular, do you know how to explicitly construct a sequence $(x_n)$ such that the $\delta_n$ neighborhoods whose image are in $\epsilon$ neighborhoods necessarily have $\delta_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove it directly. For example, for (1) use that $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| \leq |\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}|$:

Then you have $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|^2 \leq |\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}||\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| = |x - y|$

So for $\delta := \varepsilon^2$ you get $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| < \varepsilon$.